# Faster RCNN in Python cfg file

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

What does `PROPOSAL_METHOD: gt` signify, in the faster_rcnn_end2end.yml file?

Does is mean that the ROI proposals are the Ground Truth Bounding Boxes only?

The link to the file is [here](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/experiments/cfgs/faster_rcnn_end2end.yml)

Comment: Not sure, but faster rcnn uses RPN (regional propagation network) to generate proposal windows not ground truth. Why don't you try commenting out this line and see if there is any effect on training or testing.

Comment: Opening an issue on [py-faster-rcnn github](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn)  will get you a quicker response to this specific projects configuration.